# Dimension of fully connected layers

Tags: keras, deep-learning

[image: This image includes the structure of Inception v3 model taken from InceptionV3 description]

I didn't understand the patch size and the input size of the fully connected layers. Why the first connected layer has input with 3 dimensions?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

### Patch size for fully connected layers

It's simply the size of the weight matrix of each fully connected layer. For example the first fully connected layer takes a `5x5x2048=51200` sized input and produces `1024` sized output. Therefore it has a `51200 x 1024` weight matrix

#### Input size

It's an image of size 224x224 with 3 channels. Three channels are simply the RGB channels.